# sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal does not work

Tags: 13.04, nautilus-extensions

I newly installed Ubuntu 13.04.I want to install nautilus open terminal facility.When i execute `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal` it says: `Unable to locate package nautilus-open-terminal.`What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

**1)** Open the **"Software Sources"** application.

[image]

**2)** Make sure you have enable the "universe" repository, or you should enable it.

[image]

**3)** Close the software source app and open a Termianl and type:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal`

The package "nautilus-open-terminal" is in universe repository.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/gnome/nautilus-open-terminal

Comment: It appears that one more step may be required. On the Terminal type: nautilus -q

Comment: Is there a way to enable this universe repository from the command line?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the correct package name is: `nautilus-open-terminal-here

So:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal-here
```

In the future you could use good old Synaptic to find packages you need:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

With synaptic it is easy to search and manage packages when in trouble. More detailed that Software center and simpler to handle than command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it gives the same error.It can not locate the package.